# Prove $x+y+x=xyz$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $X=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:x+y+z=xyz\right\}$  is an unbounded set.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Fix two coordinates as high as you want, and find an appropriate value for the last one.

Answer (score 4):

Take $(x,y,z) = (n, -n, 0), n\in\mathbb{R}$.